# Paypal Implicit Payments without redirecting to Paypal in paypal api c# asp.net

Tags: api, paypal

I want to generate pay request in paypal using Paypal Api. I am using the following 
reference link https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/pay-api-operation 
But they people have not explained how to use that code in c#. I want to give a button to user  and he'll fill the oauth key and payment request will be sent to merchant account.

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample codes are here

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-code-samples

PayPal provides Web Service API for the following methods -

1) Website Payments Pro

2) Payflow Gateway

3) PayPal Express Checkout

### Updated - 9/11/2014

PayPal provides [REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/) now.

In addition, sample code is moved to [GitHub](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/sample-apps/)

Comment: This URL is now broken sadly